# Development and production on the same vps server?

Tags: laravel, development-environment, dev-to-production

I'm currently using a vps plan at vpsdime.com as my development server. I move a lot and use different computers so didn't want to develop locally.

Soon, I'll be able to launch my webapp (approx 5-10 users to start with). Should I simply install my production app on my same vps server, or would you advise to get another server? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely use the same server. Just make sure everything as separated per environment:

- Different Redis database
- Different MySQL database
- Different Elasticsearch server
- Different location to store session data
- Different caching location
- Different queues (Redis/Beanstalk, ...)
- Different AWS bucket
- Different ... you get the gist.

It should be straightforward to setup different vhosts with Apache or Nginx.

Comment: Thanks @hannesvdreken